# Restrict redshift user/group to a single database in a single Redshift cluster that has multiple databases

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, database-administration

I am currently trying to utilize a group that I created which has read only/select permissions for a particular schema in a Redshift database.

This database lives on a Redshift cluster which contains multiple other DBs.

**The problem:**

I noticed that when I add/drop a user from the group while connected to the database as the super user the change happens across all of the databases that exist on the cluster instead of just the single instance I would like the change to occur on.

I tried altering the group using add/drop for each user, i expected this to only make this change in the DB instance I was connected to as the super user but instead it made changes to all of the DBs in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Users are not restricted to one database but the entire Redshift cluster as per [Redshift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Users.html#r_Users-creatingaltering-and-deleting-users)

> Database users are global across a data warehouse cluster (and not for each individual database).

Although the documentation does not explicitly explains whether that also holds for [groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Groups.html), I strongly suspect that groups are also cluster-wide.

So to fix your issue, you would need to use several groups with different sets of members.